# How to run the python shell inside a terminal in Windows?

Tags: python

I've scrolled the internet all over and theres no simple, clean explanation for this. How can I open the Python shell, but inside a terminal window such as CMD? I have an application for it, but want to run it inside a terminal, so I can practice Python code inside my IDE like VS code.

Comment: Open up a command prompt and type "python"?

Comment: Do you mean to run python like this: C:\User\abc>python a.py?

Comment: `so I can practice Python code inside my IDE like VS code`, in fact, `VS` just do same thing as `open cmd, and type python in cmd, give your a REPL to run your input`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reasonably new version of Python you need to run `py.exe` (or just `py`) instead of `python.exe`, because the real python executable (`python.exe`) is not in your path environment variable by default, whereas `py.exe` is in the `/windows` directory and thus automatically in path.

So to run your script type `py yourscript.py` from the directory of your script. If you just run `py` it will start the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Look e.g. at https://www.python-course.eu/python3_execute_script.php

Under the title **Start a Python script** (almost at the beginning)
there is an instruction. Just write from the command prompt:

- *python*,
- a space,
- and the filename containing your script, with *.py* extension.

As in each command, press *Enter* and your script will be executed.

Of course, I assume that you have installed *Python* on your computer.
If this is not the case, start from installing it.

I have quite a new *Python* version installed (3.6.5) and start *Python*
writing just *python*. Writing just *py* also does the job, but (IMHO)
it is not necessary.

If you want to start *Python* interpreter and play around with some
*Python* commands, write just *python* and *Enter*. The interpreter will
start and display its own command prompt (*>>>*).